# Is STL allowed to call destructor more than one time on element of a container

Tags: stl, destructor

Basically I have a strange problem, I have a struct Node that inherits from counter struct. And in the counter struct I have this check to make "sure" that Destructor is called only on allocated memory and that it is called only once.

```
static atomic < int > check;

counter()
      {
          check=42;
//...
      }

 ~counter() 
    {
        if (check!=42)
        {
            cout<<"ouch"<< typeid(T).name()<<"  "<< check<<"  "<< objects_created<< endl;
            sleep(1);
            assert(0);
        }
        check=84;
     //...
    }
```

and it breaks when compiled with g++4.6

```
3  0x00007ffff65ec7a4 in counter<Node>::~counter (this=0x614c60, 
    __in_chrg=<value optimized out>)
    at /home...


4  0x00007ffff65e7a4d in Node::~Node (this=0x614c60, 
    __in_chrg=<value optimized out>)
    at /home...


5  0x00007ffff6603cf2 in std::_Destroy<Node> (__pointer=0x614c60)
    at /usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/stl_construct.h:92


6  0x00007ffff6600004 in std::_Destroy_aux<false>::__destroy<Node*> (
    __first=0x614c60, __last=0x614d40)
    at /usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/stl_construct.h:102


7  0x00007ffff65fa003 in std::_Destroy<Node*> (__first=0x614c60, 
    __last=0x614d40) at /usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/stl_construct.h:125


8  0x00007ffff65f2a4f in std::_Destroy<Node*, Node> (__first=0x614c60, 
    __last=0x614d40) at /usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/stl_construct.h:151


9  0x00007ffff65ecfb2 in std::vector < Node, std::allocator < Node>
>::~vector (
    this=0x7ffff68329f8, __in_chrg= < value optimized out>)
    at /usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/stl_vector.h:348
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`check` is static, which means that it is shared by all instances of the class. Since you want `check` to be a normal class member, you should remove the `static` keyword.

Comment: ouch, so embarrassing, often I hvae bugs in bugs haunting code :P  tnx... Probably question should be removed, but Ill accept your answer.